# Execute the same entrypoint script on docker container restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

Is there any way to re-execute the entrypoint script when a docker container/service restarts after failure?

I am deploying using docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml abcstack.

This compose file contains multiple services.

Answer (score 1):

[ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), when added to the dockerfile, are always executed when a container is starting.

Comment: My best understanding is that in dev the ENTRYPOINT is not executed by visual studio.  Instead it runs the commands externally on the container to optimize start time for debug. Because of this these commands don't get run a second time.
I may be wrong, but euther way ENTRYPOINT  is not working for me